# Oracle Query to get

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, oracle11g

Hi I have a peculiar requirement :

Generate a report calculating retention of customers for each week (last 8 week, week must start on mon and end on sun).

1) report is for 8 iso week (Mon-Sun), if I run report today i.e 10/23/2014 it should take data till 10/19/2014(week#42) back to 08/25/2014(week#35) and calculate retention for each week.So total 8 week...
This part I have completed using TRUNC(sysdate-7,'IW') & group by count for each week

But below point is getting harder for me 
2) for each week the total cust count should be :
all the customers active before last day of previous week (i.e Sun of previous week)
for iso week 35

```
Start       End       : Calculate all the customers before 08/25/2014    -- A1
8/25/2014   8/31/2014
```

then calculate all customers who bought product in last 30 days i.e from 07/25/2014 to 08/24/2014. --A2

Retention % = A2/A1

the total for week 35 will be different

```
Start       End       : Calculate all the customers before 09/01/2014 --B1
9/1/2014  9/7/2014
```

then calculate all customers who bought product in last 30 days i.e from 08/01/2014 to 8/31/2014.  --B2

Retention % = B2/B1

Comment: Give some sample input, expected output and whatever code you have thus far...

Comment: Input is a table having date and customer ID,output should be total customers for each week...

Comment: Hambone was talking about example **data** and the expected output of the data. Ideally set up a little http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: CREATE TABLE Table1
 (`cust_id` int, `enrollment_date` datetime, `product_type` varchar(1))
;
 
INSERT INTO Table1
 (`cust_id`, `enrollment_date`, `product_type`)
VALUES
 (123456, '2014-08-25 00:00:00', 'X'),
 (423482, '2014-08-26 00:00:00', 'X'),
 (210424, '2014-09-01 00:00:00', 'X'),
 (434242, '2014-09-01 00:00:00', 'X'),
 (500342, '2014-09-08 00:00:00', 'X'),
 (805423, '2014-09-15 00:00:00', 'X'),
 (423344, '2014-09-22 00:00:00', 'X'),
 (502344, '2014-09-29 00:00:00', 'X'),
 (211043, '2014-10-06 00:00:00', 'X'),
 (234443, '2014-10-13 00:00:00', 'X')
;

Comment: for last 8 weeks we have to generate report :